Averaging over labels instances for SVM classification
This is a hypothetical question about different ways to input training/testing data into an SVM model. I have 128 instances for each of two classes, that can be heirarchally grouped into 4 sets (i.e. 4 sets of 32 instances of each class). Normally, I would cross-validate the SVM by training the classifier on 3 sets (128 instances of each class) and decoding of the left out set (32 instances of each class) and iterate over all combinations of training and test.
Someone told me a better way would be to take the average of each set, so that I just have one mean feature vector per set before training/testing. This would mean that I would be training the SVM on 3 mean instances per class label, and testing on 1 left out instance per label. The argument is that these mean patterns are more stable.
I've run simulation and do get better decoding from this, but I've never seen anyone use this method before. Is there any disadvantage to using taking the average of class labels like this?
